# Who handled my event

Tags: c#, wpf, routedevent, lostfocus

I have registered to a LostFocus event on a TextBox and yet the event is not catch - my guess is that someone else handled it.
I've tried using snoop but it only shows me the MouseDown and MouseUp events (and I need the LostFocus).
Any ideas on how can I find out?

Thanks

Update:
Not so clear but the code where I register is:

eventInfo.AddEventHandler(cloningObject, eventDelegate);

Comment: Have you connected the LostFocus event to any function?

Comment: Any hints (code) on what you got so far would be welcome.

Comment: Added code sample - not so clear but this is how I register to the event

Answer (score 0):

In the XAML, make sure you assign a name to your TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" />
```

Create a function in your code behind to handle the event:

```
public void MyLostFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // ...
}
```

And then in your window's constructor (assuming this is in a window):

```
MyTextBox.LostFocus += MyLostFocusHandler;
```

Note also there is another event, `LostKeyboardFocus`.

Comment: I suppose this doesn't necessarily answer your question of why your event isn't firing, but I've never seen an event registered like you're doing.